# Silverlight wcf service - change return value of method

Tags: wcf, silverlight

In my service i had a method returning a bool, but I later changed it to a IList, I updated the
service by right clicking on the service reference and made an update. The update however did not update the method return value. To this code I get a error message that says "Cannot implicitly convert type bool to System.Collection.Generic.IList<..>"

```
patientService.SavePatient(personID, firstName, lastName, causeOfVisit,(s, e) => PatientData = e.Result);
```

The method in the service:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public IList<Patient> SavePatient(string personId, string firstName, string lastName, DateTime TimeOfArrival, string causeOfVisit)
    {
        patientRepository.SavePatient(personId, firstName, lastName, TimeOfArrival, causeOfVisit);
        return patientRepository.Patients;
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using `Silverlight-enabled WCF service` or just `WCF` service?

Comment: Did you restart the service before updating the service reference?

Comment: Silverlight-enabled WCF service! Restart?

Comment: Remove the reference and try adding again

Comment: I did that, did not work.

Comment: @user3411227 In WCF service are you getting data from database using Entity Framework ? Please post your WCF service SavePatient(..) method

Comment: No, i have all the data in a class. Sure, I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed returning a bool to IList did you Build the Solution in Build at top menu before you made Update Service Reference? because what it seems to me is that its still returning bool since you forgot that step, its needed those two steps one update in the Server side(Projectname.web) where you define the WCF by build solution and the client side as you did well with the update the Service Reference.

---

```
WCFservice.TopicInfoAsync(query_topics, (int)numberOfTopics);
WCFservice.TopicInfoCompleted += (Stopicinfo, EAtopicinfo) =>
{
   TopicList = EAtopicinfo.Result;
}
```

Comment: in your wcfservice patientService isn't it attach to a Async like the code added in my comment and then another event for when its completed and returns,it seems like you do that in that one line of code but shouldn't you be calling the SavePatientAsync??

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment but patientService is a class which has a variable of the service. The method savePatient calls client.SavePatientCompleted += callBack;
            client.SavePatientAsync(personId, firstName, lastName, DateTime.Now, causeOfVisit); Where client is the service.